# Google map doesn't show on Firefox when using HTML5 geolocation (using Meteor js)

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, firefox, meteor

I'm using Meteor to create an app and google map is not showing when using HTML5 geolocation in firefox.
Everything works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox.

I've copied the code on gist and deployed app so you can check it out.
I don't think it is CSS because it works in Firefox when I remove geolocation code from project.

Deployed test app link:
http://firefox.test.meteor.com

Gist link:
https://gist.github.com/drag0/6744120

Comment: Works for me in the latest version of FF, but does take more time to display that Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me too.

Check that the geo.enabled pref is set to true in about:config. Also, if you are using OSX you could check that Location services are enabled for Firefox under System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Location Services.